# Simple click through game template? Javascript and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, game-engine

I'm trying to build an old fashioned non-animated story based game. No real time battles or anything but, multi-player. The game would center around super heroes or villains, you could join a team made up of other players, battle each other or other teams, etc. There seems to very little I can find on frame-works for this sort of game. Everything seems to be talking about graphics, sprites, canvas, etc. This is going to be old-fashioned HTML and javascript with (probably) MYSQL as the database to store player data, inventory, money, etc. It will be Facebook integrated too.

Is there such a thing as a "framework" or "template" I could use/buy to build such a game? My experience is in html and javascript so creating a game from complete scratch is out of the question.

Thanks!

Comment: what would you require of such a framework? I don't know any, but I'm interested in the functionality you would expect of one :)

Comment: I guess just the ability to transact against a database and query it for player data. The game would more or less be like navigating a website only with a little meaning behind the clicks. Monetizing would come from some sort of currency needed for special items in the game.

Comment: I'm sure you can easily do that yourself, no need for a framework. Maybe you can try out [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) which is very popular at this time and since you know a little bit of JavaScript you don't have to learn a new language.

Comment: Google about `Frontend` and `Backend`. Maybe after that you can ask a more precise Question. In the current State it is Offtopic: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.